# Server Ubuntu strange connection behaviour - static IP

Tags: networking, server, ssh, apache2, static-ip

I've an Ubuntu server 18.04 with a static IP address, and the follow is the /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml file:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    enp3s0:
        dhcp4: no
        dhcp6: no
        addresses: [192.168.1.123/24]
        gateway4: 192.168.1.1
        nameservers:
            addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

I can download files and have internet access with this connection when I am logged in. I can also connect remotely (locally) to it with putty, without any problem. I have also installed on it a localhost site in apache, and I can always access this site locally with other notebooks.

But.. my router view the server connection only if I am logged as a user in the server, remotely with Putty or not remotely. The same thing happens when I try to view the localhost website from outside with a public IP: I view the website only if I am logged as a user in the server.

Then, after I log out the browser output change in ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, whereas locally I can continue to access it. The router in that moments view the Ethernet cable connected, with a green dot, but the server machine hasn't a green dot anymore, thus disconnected. The strange thing is that I can continue to talk remotely with it locally.

In the router I have set the port mapping on both 80 and 443 ports. The website has enabled the permanent redirect on the https:// connection.

Could someone help me, please?